# How to replace custom tags or expression with value from database in Dynamic Email Template

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, replace

Hi I am getting an email template from frontend. This Email Templates looks like:

```
Hi {{USER}},
We have created an account for you. Here are your details:
Email:{{EMAIL}}
Password:{{PASSWORD}}
```

and I am saving this email template in database. Later while any new user signs up I want to send above email template replacing the `USER with username`, `{{EMAIL}} with email of user` and `{{PASSWORD}} with password of user`

I am struck at how can I find this tags or expression from above template and replace it with any dynamic values from db. Let say this values are USER:Test Email: test@test.com and Password: 123456

Comment: What version of Laravel 5 are you using?

Comment: Laravel 5.7 @Rwd

Comment: Is there a reason you're saving it to the database instead of just creating a blade file for it?

Comment: yes, why dont you store this in the balde and pass the variables?

Comment: Actually there is multiple templates for different purposes and its manageable from admin side, so I prefer this way @Rwd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There needs to be some kind of consistency in data if you want to make your email dynamic which I believe it is as you have given an example.

or maybe I am not getting it right but why don't you just use the whole placeholder to recognize what to replace with what?

Like create a table lets say `mappings` with two custom column (other than id and timestamps one), let's say `label` and `field`

and there you could store values like:

```
| label        | field    |
|--------------|----------|
| {{USER}}     | username |
| {{EMAIL}}    | email    |
| {{PASSWORD}} | password |
```

Then you can use that table to replace the correct label with correct field value from the database.